# Is there a way to work with tabulate and jinja2?

Tags: python, jinja2, prettytable

I have this issue where I use PrettyTable to generate tables with content coming from a json file[Json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcwQe.png) I get the correct layout in terminal[Printing in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPxUk.png) but when i put it inside a jinja file the spacing are messed up[Output of jinja using PIL to obtain an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au4Bm.png)

Here's the code for creating the table[Code for table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLXg4.png)
And here's the jinja2 part [Jinja code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4VQR.png)

I tried to change the parameters of Prettytable for column width but without success.
Do I need to use len() on the string that I use and then reduce or add space to produce a correct ouput ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your goal is to display aligned table in jinja

You can use len() on the string in your script but i think it is better to generate correct spacing in jinja. You separate view code from your script code.

I think the correct way to create a beautiful table in jinja is by using css code.

You can save your table as html elements to a file, for instance:

```
html_table = x.get_html_string()


# from pathlib import Path
# `cwd`: use current directory
    cwd = Path.cwd()

    with Path(f"{cwd}/templates/my_table.html").open(mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as fp:
        fp.write(html_table)
```

then you can render it to any template and include this table in a Jinja template by using :

```
{% include 'my_table.html' %}
```

This will display the table and you can style it however you like.